# Does sketch export to XML?

Tags: sketch-app, android

Does sketch export to XML? Is a plugin required? If yes, is designing layout by exporting XML worth-while?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean SVG? SVG is an XML format.

Comment: Right. No I mean for UI XML for mobile.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. I tried googling it but no luck.   I think you'd need to convert the assets manually, one by one. You can convert SVG assets to Android XML using Android Studio's Vector Asset Studio.  There are tutorials on youtube if you get stuck.